# Alternating behaviour of a function: How to detect function caller?

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I have a function that toggles a flag everytime when it is called, which is done repeatedly, to have a alternating behaviour everytime the function is called. But what if i call the function multiple times, with different parameters? Of course my toggle-flag should only be toggled by the same function call. Is there a way to detect, have kind of a static behaviour of the flag, but one behaviour for each function caller?

```
void showText(uint8_t col, uint8_t line, const char *text, bool blinking)
{
    if(blinking)
    {
        static bool flag = false;           
        
        if(flag)
        {
            lcd_setcursor(col, line);
            for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
            {
                lcd_data(' ');
            }
        }       
        else
        {
            lcd_setcursor(col, line);
            lcd_string(text);       
        }
        
        flag = !flag;

    }
    
    else
    {
        lcd_setcursor(col, line);
        lcd_string(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're saying if `funcA` calls `showText` it should do `thingA` every time, and if `funcB` calls `showText` it should do `thingB` every time?

Comment: Pass the address of the flag INTO the function (where it is toggled). Each caller will pass its own unique flag.

Comment: You would like to try [this esoteric programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL), which has `do come from`. It might simplify this kind of task... :-D

Comment: @yano basically the function is doing the same for funcA and funcB, but when B calls right after A, the B-call toggles the flag and the next A-cycle is not as intended..

Answer (score 2):

```c
void showText( uint8_t col, uint8_t line, const char *text, bool blinking, bool* flag_ptr ) {
   ...

   if ( *flag_ptr ) { ... } else { ... }

   *flag_ptr = !*flag_ptr;

   ...
}
```

Call site A:

```c
static bool flag = false;  
showText( ..., &flag );
```

Call site B:

```c
static bool flag = false;  
showText( ..., &flag );
```

Comment: Thanks, i think thats the easiest solution thats working. Basically every caller passes its own flag to toggle! Great :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also have the flag pointer be the decision for blinking itself:

```
static bool blinkstat1 = false;
static bool blinkstat2 = false;
// Show with blinking
showText(col1, line1, text1, &blinkstat1);
// Show with blinking
showText(col2, line2, text2, &blinkstat2);

// Show text1 again w/o blinking
showText(col1, line1, text1, NULL);


void showText(uint8_t col, uint8_t line, const char *text, bool* blinking ) {
    lcd_setcursor(col, line);
    if (blinking != NULL) {
        // Blink
        if ( *blinking ) { 
            for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
                lcd_data(' ');
            }
        } else { 
            lcd_string(text);
        }
        *blinking = !*blinking;
    } else {
        // Just show text non-blinking
        lcd_string(text);
    }
}
```